# Property does not exist on this collection instance: Why?

Tags: laravel, exception

I'm working on a website which sells retro videogames using Laravel for a personal project, and I'm struggling with displaying some data (ie. I'm trying to display the multiple genres of a game).I stumbled upon the `Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance` error and I can't seem to find how to solve this problem. Here's what I did so far:

index.blade.php:

```
<div>
        @foreach ($games as $game)
            <div>
                <img src="{{ $game->cover }}" alt="{{ $game->title }}">
                <div>
                    <h3>
                        <a href="/game/{{ $game->id }}">
                            {{ $game->title }}
                        </a>
                    </h3>
                    <p>
                        {{ $game->release_year}}
                        {{ number_format($game->price, 2, ',', '.') }}
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        {{ $game->genres->name}} //Triggers the error
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
```

Game Model functions

```
public function genres(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Genre::class);
    }

    public function consoles(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Console::class);
    }
```

Genre Model function

```
public function games(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Game::class);
    }
```

I tried the following:

```
@foreach ($game->genres as $genre)

        {{ $genre->name }}

@endforeach
```

I expected it to display the multiple genres of a game, but I'm pretty new to programming in general so I must say I was not really surprised when it didn't display anything, but at least I got no errors.

Comment: try `dd()` the value of `$genre`

Comment: the `genres` relationship returns many so it will always be a Collection ... whether that Collection contains anything is a different story

Comment: Change this line ` {{ $game->genres->name}}` to ` {{ $game->genres->implode('name', ', ') }} `

Answer (score 0):

you might not be fetching genres along with games

```
$games = Games::query()->with(['genres'])->get();
```

Hope this helps